# Modelling for similarity between two descriptions

Tags: nlp, similarity, semantic-similarity

I have a dataset of companies and research projects that they were involved in. A subset of the dataset is shown below.

[image]

I am trying to find a way to model similarity between the company and the research projects using this description.

For each pair of descriptions, I would like to output a number, similar to cosine similarity, which will indicate how similar the description in second column is, to the project title in third column.

How can I go about this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

So the questions asks for how to compute similarity between the organisation description and project titles.

One initial thought would be to use a Doc2Vec model ([concept](https://medium.com/wisio/a-gentle-introduction-to-doc2vec-db3e8c0cce5e), [implementation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html)), which will take the organisation descriptions and project titles as input and output a n-dimensional vector in semantic space for the given text.

From this, you can at least has a baseline which you can use with cosine similarity to see how similar the organisation description is to the project title.

Comment: Thanks for the link. A few further technical details would be nice. Following https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/core/run_similarity_queries.html#sphx-glr-download-auto-examples-core-run-similarity-queries-py :
1) I'm a bit unclear on what I need to install and where I can find it, I have Python, pandas, numpy etc but nothing specific for NLP as yet.
2)  when constructing the corpus, should I include the org descriptions as many times as they appear or just once each?
3)  any guidelines to choosing an appropriate value of num_topics (dimensionality of LSI space I guess)?

Comment: also is there a way of using a pre-trained model (for, say, tokens) to improve the performance, compared to just reproducing exactly what goes on in https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/core/run_similarity_queries.html